# Query doesn't fetch all results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a bit of a problem with a query I made, it doesn't fetch all the results there are. It should at least come up with 3 rows but only comes up with one:

```
SELECT * FROM n_news WHERE article_id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT article_id FROM nk_article_category 
WHERE category_id IN (2,10,11,12))
ORDER BY article_featured DESC,article_published DESC
```

[image: screenshot DB]

Anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong? MySQL didn't find any errors. Thanks in advance
Left is article_id and right = category_id in table nk_article_category. There is one result way up but didn't see the point to show the whole table

Comment: 18,20 are two distinct article ids

Comment: Can you post the data rows you're expecting to see?  That way we can compare it to your query.  And the structure of the 2 tables as well.  Also, run the sub-query by itself and see what results it comes up with.  Just noticed you posted an image, but I can never see those for some reason - not sure what it's showing.

Comment: Not sure how to display that neatly, but the subquery does return the right rows

Comment: Okay, sorry, it's my corporate firewall blocking the image but I managed to get around it.  Just run the sub-query and see if it's returning the ID values you're expecting.  Then replace the sub-query with the list of ID values returned, and see what that returns.

Comment: Hey @PhillipXT Managed to find a sql structure problem by replacing the subquery, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I see per your posted query data image, your query returning correct result. the rows are all distinct (it will be considered duplicate if both article_id and category_id are same in multiple rows).

BTW, you can change your posted query to a `INNER JOIN` instead of using sub query like

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM n_news t1
INNER JOIN nk_article_category t2
ON t1.article_id = t2.article_id
AND t2.category_id IN (2,10,11,12)
ORDER BY t1.article_featured DESC, t1.article_published DESC;
```